# ncurses before login during linux boot

Tags: linux, passwords, ncurses, tty

I am debugging an ncurses program, echo and line-buffering is disabled by

```
initscr();
cbreak();
noecho();
```

which works well when I run it in the console (monitor and keyboard connected to it) and in an terminal connected by ssh.

However it needs to be run during the Linux boot process before login, which is called by a script under /etc/init.d/rc3.d/. The program asks password for mounting a disk.

The program behaviors like cbreak and noecho is not called at all. The password is echo-ed and the input is line-buffered since I cannot see the output of the program until I press ENTER.

I suspect this is because getty is not yet started to initialize the tty during boot-up which is necessary for curses, but I'm not sure.

Any idea about how to use curses in such conditions?

Best regards.

Comment: You might not have `TERM` set yet in your environment at that point.

Comment: Thanks lanzz, I confirmed $TERM is "linux" and "tty" command outputs "/dev/console" right before the program is called in the script.